# icpRenderer.on not firing on React side of app

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, electron

I am using Electron do make a desktop version on my Ionic React app. I've decided that the splash screen is only going to disappear when the React app says it can.

In `index.ts` (the main Electron file), I create an event listener like this:

```
ev = splashScreen.on(splashScreen.events.APP_READY_TO_START, () => {
    splashScreen.off(ev, true);

    splashScreen.destroy();
    mainWindow.show();
}, true);
```

This listens for the `OL-APP_START_SPLASH_CLOSE` event through `ipcMain`. The `on` function looks like this:

```
on(event: string, fn: () => any, isExternal?: boolean) {
    this.activeEvents.push({
        [isExternal ? "EXTERNAL_" + event : event]: fn
    });
    if (isExternal) ipcMain.on(event, fn);
}
```

Following the event listener, I call an update function which (temporarily) delays execution for 7 seconds. After that, I emit an event:

```
splashScreen.emit(splashScreen.events.UPDATE_CHECK_FINISHED, true);
```

where `emit` is:

```
emit(event: string, isExternal?: Boolean) {
    this.activeEvents.forEach(e => {
        if (!Object.keys(e)[0].startsWith("EXTERNAL_")) e[event].bind(this).call(); //If it's an external event (i.e. `ipcMain`) then don't run callback
    });

    if (isExternal) this.splashScreen.webContents.send(event);
}
```

On the React side, in `componentDidMount` I have:

```
ipc.on("OL-CHECKED_FOR_UPDATES", () => {
    ipc.send("OL-APP_START_SPLASH_CLOSE");
});
```

This will signal the splash screen to close only when updates have finished being checked for. When I emit the `OL-CHECKED_FOR_UPDATES` event this event listener should be called however it isn't.
I am able to send events fine (`ipc.send` works on it's own) but no matter what I do, I can't get it to listen for events.
I know these are being fired because if I move the event listener into any other script (ie index.ts) the event listener will fire, so it is only there it won't fire.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to sleep on it. Of course, if I create two different windows, they're going to have different render processes so when I emit an event on one, I'm not going to be able to receive it on the other.

All I had to do was send the event from the main window (the one displaying the react app) instead of the splash screen.